# implicit declaration of function when compiling kernel module

Tags: driver, kernel-module, implicit-declaration

I am new to working in kernel space, so I hope someone can help me with the issue I am having.

I have seen a lot of questions related to implicit declaration of function for userspace c/c++ programs, but I think the issue I am having may be approached differently in kernel space.

The code I am working on is to test out signaling a user application from the driver, which I have working, but the issue was I could not use the function send_sig_info declared in linux/signal.h until I had declared it in the header of my own driver source. I figured if I had included to correct header to access the function call declared there, it should work.

So without the declaration of send_sig_info in my own header:

```
error: implicit declaration of function ‘send_sig_info’
```

And then adding to my header file:

```
static int send_sig_info(int sig, struct siginfo *info, struct task_struct *p);
```

would allow my code to compile just fine.

Does anyone have an idea why this is?

Thanks.

Comment: In the current kernel(4.3) the function is declared in `linux/sched.h` (Presizely at lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L2483). Which kernel version you use?

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using kernel 3.10.

Comment: For your kernel the function is declared in the same file as in 4.3. You can easly check that with that site.

Comment: @user2884074 Did you find a solution to the problem?

Comment: It's moved to `linux/sched/signal.h` since 4.11 and 4.20 has changed `siginfo` to `kernel_siginfo`.